# Programmatically configure TTL, Max Size , Eviction policy for IMap in ClientConfig using HazelcastClient

Tags: hazelcast, hazelcast-imap

I am using **Hazelcast native java client to connect remote Hazelcast cluster**.
Below is the code, I want to configure **TTL, Max Size , Eviction policy** for below `IMap tranMap` from the java client.

Can anyone suggest how to set this parameters from the hazelcast client for each IMap.
I know how to configure it at cluster level in hazelcast.xml. But for my application use case, I have to configure it programmatically in ClientConfig object used in creating HazelcastClient instance.

```
    ClientConfig config = new ClientConfig();
    String[] addresses = { "192.178.11.01:5701", "192.178.30.18:5702" };
    config.getNetworkConfig().addAddress(addresses);
    HazelcastInstance hazelcastInstance = HazelcastClient.newHazelcastClient(config);
    IMap<Integer, Transaction> map = hazelcastInstance.getMap("tranMap");
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if you don't want to re-configure an existing map but just add a new configuration for a map which you'll going to use, it is doable

```
    HazelcastInstance client = HazelcastClient.newHazelcastClient();

    Config config = client.getConfig();


    config.addMapConfig(new MapConfig()
            .setName("foo")
            .setTimeToLiveSeconds(10));
```

Remember to not create the map before configuring, so `getMap` call should be after you add the config.

Answer (score 0):

This is already requested, https://github.com/hazelcast/hazelcast/issues/14750, but not yet implemented

Comment: btw if you don't want to re-configure an existing map but just add a new configuration for a map which you'll going to use, it is doable.